# Color Plastic Sheeps As Game Pawns

Tags: identify-this-game, custom-game-pieces

For years I've been trying to remember what game was this I played as a kid mid-1980's.

It had a huge board and within the board there was a road. The board tiles were drawn stone-like. There were also cards involved but I can't remember any mechanics.

What I remember the most are the player pawns, that were made of hard, shiny plastic in vivid colours and had the shape of sheep. Given that it was played in a Christian environment, I think it was some sort of Christian-focused game, but I'm not 100% sure if that was the purpose of the game.

The sheep pawns were rather simplistic and had only two legs and the body looked like rings together.

Thing is that I would love to have them but people don't seem to remember that game.

It's not any farming game, nothing with the word "sheep" in the title and it's not a pre-scholar game. I was the only kid among a group of young adults.